# Realm .Net - Unable To Restore Realm.Database Package

Tags: xamarin, realm

When I am running [DrawX](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/examples/DrawXNative/iOS/packages.config) sample I have an unrestored package "Realm.Database".

When I am searching this package on Nuget - there are no results.

Is "Realm.Database" removed already and I have to use something different?

SushiHangover, I understand, thank you!

Comment: The `DrawX` sample app is based up an **upcoming release** that supports the new `Realm Mobile Platform`. You would need to build Realm from source, but they are committing changes daily, even hourly ;-) so it would be very unstable alpha code right now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, as @SushiHangover explained, this is part of an upcoming release. It will be removed from our examples folder to avoid further confusion.

We don't *quite* manage to commit hourly around-the-clock but the pace of development has been fairly quick in recent time ;-) The rate of API-breaking changes will probably be a lot slower from now on.

Some of the changes have been put in place to support the new Realm Mobile Platform but many were there to help with data binding.